# bot.send_message(message.chat.id) Не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('<token>')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def starting(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_zakaz = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Сделать заказ', callback_data='zakaz')
    item_price = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Прайс', callback_data='price')
    item_dop = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Доп.Информация', callback_data='dop_inf')
    markup.add(item_zakaz, item_price, item_dop)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вас приветствует бот, снизу вы можете сделать заказ. И узнать важную информацию. (Что-бы отобразить сообщение снова, напишите "/start")',
    reply_markup= markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer (message):
    if message.data == "price":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Аватарка: Шапка: Превью:")

    elif message.data == "dop_inf":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"За доп.информацией, обращайтесь к ")
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Answer (score 0):

В функции

```
bot.send_message()
```

Вы не закрыли скобку, а так-же поставили "," в конце строки. Правильный вариант:

```
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вас приветствует бот, снизу вы можете сделать заказ. И узнать важную информацию. (Что-бы отобразить сообщение снова, напишите "/start")')
```